# Does the Task Parallel Library (or PLINQ) take other processes into account?

Tags: task-parallel-library

In particular, I'm looking at using TPL to start (and wait for) external processes. Does the TPL look at total machine load (both CPU and I/O) before deciding to start another task (hence -- in my case -- another external process)?

**For example:**

I've got about 100 media files that need to be encoded or transcoded (e.g. from WAV to FLAC or from FLAC to MP3). The encoding is done by launching an external process (e.g. FLAC.EXE or LAME.EXE). Each file takes about 30 seconds. Each process is mostly CPU-bound, but there's some I/O in there. I've got 4 cores, so the worst case (transcoding by piping the decoder into the encoder) still only uses 2 cores. I'd like to do something like:

```
Parallel.ForEach(sourceFiles,
    sourceFile =>
        TranscodeUsingPipedExternalProcesses(sourceFile));
```

Will this kick off 100 tasks (and hence 200 external processes competing for the CPU)? Or will it see that the CPU's busy and only do 2-3 at a time?

Comment: Of course, what I should probably do is wire a `TaskCompletionSource` up to the `Process.Exited` event, and then have a `TranscodeAsync` method that returns `Task`. It'd then be non-blocking. Then I can have finer-grained control over the tasks while still staying in the grain of the TPL.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're going to run into a couple of issues here. The starvation avoidance mechanism of the scheduler will see your tasks as blocked as they wait on processes. It will find it hard to distinguish between a deadlocked thread and one simply waiting for a process to complete. As a result it may schedule new tasks if your tasks run or a long time (see below). The hillclimbing heuristic should take into account the overall load on the system, both from your application and others. It simply tries to maximize work done, so it will add more work until the overall throughput of the system stops increasing and then it will back off. I don't *think* this will effect your application but the stavation avoidance issue probably will.

You can find more detail as to how this all works in *[Parallel Programming with Microsoft®.NET](http://parallelpatterns.codeplex.com/)*, Colin Campbell, Ralph Johnson, Ade Miller, Stephen Toub (an earlier draft is [online](http://parallelpatterns.codeplex.com/)).

"The .NET thread pool automatically manages the number of worker
threads in the pool. It adds and removes threads according to built-in
heuristics. The .NET thread pool has two main mechanisms for injecting
threads: a starvation-avoidance mechanism that adds worker
threads if it sees no progress being made on queued items and a hillclimbing
heuristic that tries to maximize throughput while using as
few threads as possible.

The goal of starvation avoidance is to prevent deadlock. This kind
of deadlock can occur when a worker thread waits for a synchronization
event that can only be satisfied by a work item that is still pending
in the thread pool’s global or local queues. If there were a fixed
number of worker threads, and all of those threads were similarly
blocked, the system would be unable to ever make further progress.
Adding a new worker thread resolves the problem.

A goal of the hill-climbing heuristic is to improve the utilization
of cores when threads are blocked by I/O or other wait conditions
that stall the processor. By default, the managed thread pool has one
worker thread per core. If one of these worker threads becomes
blocked, there’s a chance that a core might be underutilized, depending
on the computer’s overall workload. The thread injection logic
doesn’t distinguish between a thread that’s blocked and a thread
that’s performing a lengthy, processor-intensive operation. Therefore,
whenever the thread pool’s global or local queues contain pending
work items, active work items that take a long time to run (more than
a half second) can trigger the creation of new thread pool worker
threads.

The .NET thread pool has an opportunity to inject threads every
time a work item completes or at 500 millisecond intervals, whichever
is shorter. The thread pool uses this opportunity to try adding threads
(or taking them away), guided by feedback from previous changes in
the thread count. If adding threads seems to be helping throughput,
the thread pool adds more; otherwise, it reduces the number of
worker threads. This technique is called the hill-climbing heuristic.
Therefore, one reason to keep individual tasks short is to avoid
“starvation detection,” but another reason to keep them short is to
give the thread pool more opportunities to improve throughput by
adjusting the thread count. The shorter the duration of individual
tasks, the more often the thread pool can measure throughput and
adjust the thread count accordingly.

To make this concrete, consider an extreme example. Suppose
that you have a complex financial simulation with 500 processor-intensive
operations, each one of which takes ten minutes on average
to complete. If you create top-level tasks in the global queue for each
of these operations, you will find that after about five minutes the
thread pool will grow to 500 worker threads. The reason is that the
thread pool sees all of the tasks as blocked and begins to add new
threads at the rate of approximately two threads per second.

What’s wrong with 500 worker threads? In principle, nothing, if
you have 500 cores for them to use and vast amounts of system
memory. In fact, this is the long-term vision of parallel computing.
However, if you don’t have that many cores on your computer, you are
in a situation where many threads are competing for time slices. This
situation is known as processor oversubscription. Allowing many
processor-intensive threads to compete for time on a single core adds
context switching overhead that can severely reduce overall system
throughput. Even if you don’t run out of memory, performance in this
situation can be much, much worse than in sequential computation.
(Each context switch takes between 6,000 and 8,000 processor cycles.)
The cost of context switching is not the only source of overhead.
A managed thread in .NET consumes roughly a megabyte of stack
space, whether or not that space is used for currently executing functions.
It takes about 200,000 CPU cycles to create a new thread, and
about 100,000 cycles to retire a thread. These are expensive operations.

As long as your tasks don’t each take minutes, the thread pool’s
hill-climbing algorithm will eventually realize it has too many threads
and cut back on its own accord. However, if you do have tasks that
occupy a worker thread for many seconds or minutes or hours, that
will throw off the thread pool’s heuristics, and at that point you
should consider an alternative.

The first option is to decompose your application into shorter
tasks that complete fast enough for the thread pool to successfully
control the number of threads for optimal throughput.
A second possibility is to implement your own task scheduler
object that does not perform thread injection. If your tasks are of long
duration, you don’t need a highly optimized task scheduler because
the cost of scheduling will be negligible compared to the execution
time of the task. MSDN® developer program has an example of a
simple task scheduler implementation that limits the maximum degree
of concurrency. For more information, see the section, “Further Reading,”
at the end of this chapter.

As a last resort, you can use the SetMaxThreads method to
configure the ThreadPool class with an upper limit for the number
of worker threads, usually equal to the number of cores (this is the
Environment.ProcessorCount property). This upper limit applies for
the entire process, including all AppDomains."

Comment: +1 The overload of `Parallel.ForEach` that takes a `ParallelOptions` object with a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism' could also help.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: no.

Internally, the TPL uses the standard [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) to schedule its tasks. So you're actually asking whether the `ThreadPool` takes machine load into account and it doesn't. The only thing that limits the number of tasks simultaneously running is the number of threads in the thread pool, nothing else.

Is it possible to have the external processes report back to your application once they are ready? In that case you do not have to wait for them (keeping threads occupied).

Answer (score -1):

Ran a test using TPL/ThreadPool to schedule a great number of tasks doing looped spins. Using an external app I've loaded one of the cores to 100% using proc affinity. The number of active tasks never decreased.

Even better, I ran multiple instances of the same CPU intensive .NET TPL enabled app. The number of threads for all the apps was the same, and never went below the number of cores, even though my machine was barely usable.

So theory aside, TPL uses the number of cores available, but never checks on their actual load. A very poor implementation in my opinion.

Comment: I think TPL assigns at _minimum_ a number of threads equal to the number of cores. It does check load, and may increase the number of threads, but will not decrease the number of threads below that minimum.

Comment: That's correct. That's the default for the minimum. It's a cop out. Do you expect us developers to create code that monitors the overall CPU load, exclusive of our running app, and reduce the minimum & maximum  number of threads consumed by the thread pool accordingly? Or should we manually set the minimum from the beginning to 1? Or maybe 2? Or CPU Count/2?
And btw no, it does NOT monitor the actual CPU load. It only monitors its own threads. That's all.

Comment: Something that occurs to me is that TPL is greedy, it may hill climb to the point of CPU over-subscription if that benefits the execution rate of tasks, so you are correct, TPL monitors tasks/sec and not CPU load, which has some drawbacks. My point is that I don't think Microsoft was expecting developers to change processor affinity while using TPL.

Comment: This is not exclusively about what WE're doing in our apps. There are other services and apps running simultaneously on people's computers :) This implementation assumes that a .NET app is the only one running on the machine. A possible solution to this could be for us to be able to hint the thread pool about reducing the thread priority for CPU intensive tasks. As soon as the thread is released to the thread pool, it would then reset the priority back to the default normal. Still not ideal though...