# Is it possible to change parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism during execution of a Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I am running a multi-threaded loop:

```
protected ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();

parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2;
Parallel.ForEach(items, parallelOptions, item =>
{
    // Loop code here
});
```

I want to change the `parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` during the execution of the parallel loop, to reduce or increase a number of threads.

```
parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5;
```

It doesn't seem to increase the threads. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain why you'd want to do that?  It will already ramp up the number of threads on its own up to the maximum specified if needs be, or will use less if appropriate.

Comment: Mainly to throllel the app when it is using too many resources on a server that is shared. I get the server running at 100% which degrades the responsivness of the other applications on the servers.

Comment: Is this a CPU-bound issue or other 'resources' like disk?

Comment: This case in particular is CPU, but the number of threads could effect memmory and disk as well depenting on the contents of the foreach. I would like to be able to change the total threads utilized if system resources become taxed too heavily.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488381/does-the-task-parallel-library-or-plinq-take-other-processes-into-account

Answer (score 5):

The issue with even trying to do this is that it's a hard problem.  For starters, how do you even observe CPU and disk utilization reliably?  Sampling CPU infrequently will give a poor picture of what's actually going on and sampling disk utilization is even harder.  Secondly, what is the granularity of your tasks and how often can you quickly can you actually change the number that are running.   Thirdly things change rapidly over time so you need to apply some kind of filtering to your observations.  Fourthly, the ideal number of threads will depend on the CPU that the code is actually running on.  Fifthly, if you allocate too many threads you'll be thrashing between them instead of doing useful work.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff960958.aspx for a discussion on how the Thread Pool in .NET handles the complex task of deciding how many threads to use.

You could also use reflector and take a look at the code that TPL uses to allocate threads and to avoid unnecessary context switching - it's complex and that's not even taking disk access into account!

You could instead try executing the tasks on a lower priority thread (creating your own `TaskScheduler` that runs threads with a priority of below-normal is actually quite easy).  That at least will ensure that you can run up 100% CPU without impacting the rest of the system.  Messing with thread priorities is in itself fraught with problems but if this is a purely background task it can be straightforward and might help.

Often though, disk utilization is the real culprit when it comes to other applications suffering at the hands of one greedy application.  Windows can allocate CPU fairly between applications with ease but when relatively slow disk access is involved it's quite another matter.  Instead of trying to dynamically adjust how many thread you have running you may instead need to simply throttle your application such that it doesn't access the disk too often.  That's something you can do without changing how many threads are active.

You could also look at `SetPriorityClass` as a way to inform the OS that your process is less important than other applications running on the system, see [How can I/O priority of a process be increased?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301290/how-can-i-o-priority-of-a-process-be-increased) for more information.  But that assumes your whole process is less important, not just this part of it.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't expect it to be possible to change the degree of parallelism after you've called `ForEach`.  As I understand it, `ForEach` is going to determine how many threads it can create, create that many partitions, and create the threads to operate on those partitions.  There's no point at which it can say, "Oh, wait, he changed our resource allocation, let me re-partition the array and re-allocate threads."

Comment: Yes sure i agree with your understanding, But could you please add a reference link?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant of the .NET 6 [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) API that allows to configure dynamically the degree of parallelism. It shares the same parameters and behavior with the native API, except from taking a derived version of the [`ParallelOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions) as argument (`DynamicParallelOptions`). This class has an extra property `DegreeOfParallelism`. Changing this property results in a rapid adaptation of the currently active degree of parallelism.

This implementation is based on the idea of throttling the `source` sequence of the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` API. The API itself is configured with the maximum expected value for the `DegreeOfParallelism`. The actual parallelism is limited effectively by denying the loop from free access to the source elements. An element is propagated forward every time another element is processed. The throttling itself is performed with an unbounded [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim). Changing the maximum degree of parallelism is performed by calling the `Release`/`WaitAsync` methods of the semaphore.

```
/// <summary>
/// Executes a parallel foreach operation on an asynchronous sequence, enforcing
/// a degree of parallelism that can be dynamically changed during the execution.
/// </summary>
public static Task DynamicParallelForEachAsync<TSource>(
    IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source,
    DynamicParallelOptions options,
    Func<TSource, CancellationToken, ValueTask> body)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(options);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(body);

    SemaphoreSlim throttler = new(options.DegreeOfParallelism);
    options.DegreeOfParallelismChangedDelta += Options_ChangedDelta;
    void Options_ChangedDelta(object sender, int delta)
    {
        if (delta > 0)
            throttler.Release(delta);
        else
            for (int i = delta; i < 0; i++) throttler.WaitAsync();
    }

    async IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> GetThrottledSource(
        [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        IAsyncEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetAsyncEnumerator(
            cancellationToken);
        await using (enumerator.ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await throttler.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (!await enumerator.MoveNextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)) break;
                yield return enumerator.Current;
            }
        }
    }

    return Parallel.ForEachAsync(GetThrottledSource(), options, async (item, ct) =>
    {
        try { await body(item, ct).ConfigureAwait(false); }
        finally { throttler.Release(); }
    }).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        options.DegreeOfParallelismChangedDelta -= Options_ChangedDelta;
        return t;
    }, default, TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach |
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
}

/// <summary>
/// Stores options that configure the DynamicParallelForEachAsync method.
/// </summary>
public class DynamicParallelOptions : ParallelOptions
{
    private int _degreeOfParallelism;

    public event EventHandler<int> DegreeOfParallelismChangedDelta;

    public DynamicParallelOptions(int maxDegreeOfParallelism)
    {
        // The native Parallel.ForEachAsync will see the base.MaxDegreeOfParallelism.
        base.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism;
        _degreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;
    }

    public int DegreeOfParallelism
    {
        get { return _degreeOfParallelism; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 1) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            if (value == _degreeOfParallelism) return;
            int delta = value - _degreeOfParallelism;
            DegreeOfParallelismChangedDelta?.Invoke(this, delta);
            _degreeOfParallelism = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The `DynamicParallelOptions.DegreeOfParallelism` property is not thread-safe. It is assumed that controlling the degree of parallelism will be performed by a single thread, or at least that the operations will be synchronized.

Usage example, featuring a [`Channel<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1) as the source of the parallel loop:

```
Channel<int> channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<int>();
DynamicParallelOptions options = new(maxDegreeOfParallelism: 50)
{
    DegreeOfParallelism = 2
};

await DynamicParallelForEachAsync(
    channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(), options, async (item, ct) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Processing #{item}");
        await Task.Delay(1000, ct); // Simulate an I/O-bound operation
    });
```

```
// Push values to the channel from any thread
channel.Writer.TryWrite(1);
channel.Writer.TryWrite(2);
channel.Writer.TryWrite(3);
channel.Writer.Complete();
```

```
// Set the DegreeOfParallelism to a positive value at any time from a single thread
options.DegreeOfParallelism = 5;
```

Some overloads with synchronous `source`, or synchronous `body`:

```
public static Task DynamicParallelForEachAsync<TSource>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    DynamicParallelOptions options,
    Func<TSource, CancellationToken, ValueTask> body)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);

    #pragma warning disable CS1998
    async IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> GetSource()
    { foreach (TSource item in source) yield return item; }
    #pragma warning restore CS1998

    return DynamicParallelForEachAsync(GetSource(), options, body);
}

public static void DynamicParallelForEach<TSource>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    DynamicParallelOptions options,
    Action<TSource, CancellationToken> body)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(body);
    DynamicParallelForEachAsync(source, options, (item, ct) =>
    {
        body(item, ct); return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }).Wait();
}
```

The default value of the `DegreeOfParallelism` is `Environment.ProcessorCount`. Setting the `DegreeOfParallelism` to a value larger than the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is allowed, although it doesn't have any effect. The `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` represents the hard upper limit for the effective degree of parallelism. It is recommended to configure the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` with a reasonable value. Setting it too high, for example to `Int32.MaxValue`, might increase the memory and CPU overhead of the whole operation, especially if the `source` contains a large number of elements.