# Thread Count controlling dynamically in Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am using Task Parallel Library for threading in C#.

At the moment I am starting "X" number of threads making use of `ParallelOptions` class as follows:

```
ParallelOptions opt = new ParallelOptions();
opt.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4;
Parallel.ForEach(temp, opt, (t) =>
{
 //body
});

//temp is List of strings
```

This works fine starting 4 threads for each string inside list `temp`.

My project's requirement states that the number of threads started should be controllable. I.e. for example lets say we have 100 strings and I have initiated the parallel loop with 4 threads as above. If we want to change the thread count is that possible?

Let's say 50 records have been processed with 4 threads. Now I want only to run 2 threads for the next 50 without exiting the loop. (Its just an example, number of records are not fixed).

The only way to bind this change is when thread count changes in runtime.

I tried changing `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`inside loop using lock and all but the same doesn't effect the thread count it remains 4 all along. Any help in this regards will be appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705006/is-it-possible-to-change-paralleloptions-maxdegreeofparallelism-during-execution.

Comment: _without exiting the loop_ is not really possible, use 2 loops or make it a proper Producer/Consumer pattern.