# Increase number of worker threads gradually based on success result from earlier threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

My requirement is similar to what has been asked earlier: [Is it possible to change parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism during execution of a Parallel.ForEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705006/is-it-possible-to-change-paralleloptions-maxdegreeofparallelism-during-execution), however, the reason why I want that is different.

I will try to explain the requirement using a simple example.

Suppose there is an aircraft functionality test system and to ensure that the system does not get overwhelmed seeing many failures together, the system designer has decided that first a single aircraft simulation will be run through the test suite. If it succeeds, then two simulations will be run in parallel. If these also succeed, then four and so on till a maximum value(for eg, 50). This is a hypothetical scenario, but can be easily applicable to situations where safety is of paramount importance.

Reading other similar answers on this site, it looks like it is not possible to change parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism during execution of a Parallel.ForEach loop. So I am looking for other design suggestions from the experts.

Assumption here is that there is a feedback mechanism already present which can feed the results from prior simulations (and if those results are successful, then number of threads will be increased in current simulation run).

Comment: I think you would have to do something like that by hand, without using the TPL.

Comment: Firstly, your hypothetical is hard to follow *to ensure that the system does not get overwhelmed seeing many failures together* im not sure what that means, secondly `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is only a suggestion per se, The thread pool is smart and won't use too many threads, unless it thinks it would be advantageous, if you want dedicated threads you will most likely have to build this manually using the standard `Thread` class.

Comment: Also if this is all short lived cpu bound worloads and you want to save your self a lot of time and effort . why not just create a loop and gradually increase MaxDegreeOfParallelism in Parallel.ForEach  or dataflow. Though even then how are you going to tell that the increase is actually having any actionable affect. I think in the end you will still have to roll-your-own logic and try to understand the metrics in what you are doing