# How to create one-to-one multithreading relationship and handling exception in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, exception, thread-exceptions

It's the first time that I work on multithreading application (in general, not only with C#), and for this reason I know only simple notions about it. I've realized basically implementation with `System.Threading` namespace.

I've a dictionary which link objects A with its ID (`Dictionary<int,A>`). Every A has to do an operation (the same operation for every A), and I would like that this operations work in a list of separate thread, one for each A.

I know that `System.Threading` is bad way to realize multithreading, but I know a little bit only this namespace at this moment. I made something as:

```
public class ThreadManager
{
    private Dictionary<int, A> _aList;
    public Dictionary<int, A> AList
    {
        get { return _aList; }
        set { _aList = value; }
    }

    private Dictionary<int, Thread> _threadList;
    public Dictionary<int, Thread> ThreadList
    {
        get { return _threadList; }
        set { _threadList = value; }
    }

    public ThreadManager(Dictionary<int, A> list)
    {
        AList = list;
        ThreadList = new Dictionary<int, Thread>();

        foreach (A a in AList)
        {
            int id = a.Id;
            ThreadList.Add(id, new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Operation)));
        }
    }

    public void Operation(object data)
    {
        try
        {
            /*** do something***/
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            /*** throw exception ***/
        }
    }
}
```

When I run specific thread in out point of my application code with:

```
ThreadManager.ThreadList[i].Start(data)
```

it seems work fine to do needed operation. However, I think that this solution is really ugly and not very functional.

Furthermore, there is another big problem. When exception in throw, as expected, it isn't catch out of thread. Can I catch thread exception in another point of my code, which work on different thread (for example the main thread)?

**Edit:**

In order to be clear, I would like that no threads blocking main thread. I need to be able to operate on the main thread while operations work.

Comment: Seems like you're dealing with [data parallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/data-parallelism-task-parallel-library), so you could look into using `Parallel.ForEach()` from the Task Parallel Library. Regarding your last question, make sure to only ask one question per post.

Comment: `foreach (A a in AList)` <-- This cannot be compiled.

Comment: @Julian I don't know TPL. I will read about it, thanks. 
About last item, maybe I open another question. I'm sorry

Comment: @shingo it's only an example. I know I need KP values or else like it

Comment: @Julian i noticed that Parallel.ForEach or Parallel.For will block main thread. I would like have main thread free in order to use. In other words, I need to do operations list in background

Comment: Then you should look into using Tasks, e.g. [implement the Task-Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/implementing-the-task-based-asynchronous-pattern) or use the async-await pattern all the way and kick of multiple Tasks at once and `await Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks)`. Note that parallelism, multi-threading and asynchronicity are not the same thing.

Comment: What is the type of your application? Is it Windows Forms?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes it is

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion it to use a combination of async/await, `Task.Run` and `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        button1.Enabled = false;

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ParallelOptions options = new()
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
            };

            Parallel.ForEach(dictionary, options, entry =>
            {
                var (key, value) = entry;
                /* do something with the key and value */
            });
        });
    }
    catch (AggregateException aex)
    {
        /* handle aex.InnerExceptions (can be more than one) */
    }
    finally
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

1. Using the [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) and [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) keywords allows you to write asynchronous code that doesn't block the UI thread, in the same way that you would write normal synchronous code. The UI remains responsive while the asynchronous operation is in-flight.
2. The [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) offloads the processing of the `action` delegate to a [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) thread. The `ThreadPool` is a pool of reusable threads that is managed by the .NET infrastructure. In case it is necessary, you can fine-tune it with the [`ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads) method.
3. The [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) invokes the `body` delegate in parallel on multiple `ThreadPool` threads, enforcing a [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) policy. In case you want unlimited parallelism, configure it with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1`.

In case of an exception the `Parallel.ForEach` will stop invoking the `body` delegate, and will complete when all the currently running invocations have completed. The errors of all erroneous invocations will be bundled in an [`AggregateException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception). This exception will be propagated first by the `Task.Run` and then by the `await` operator, and you will be able to handle it on the UI thread with the `try`/`catch` block inside the `Click` event handler. You could also let it unhandled (omit the `catch` block), in which case it will be handled be the general [`Application.ThreadException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception) event handler. If you omit this too, the user will be notified by the default error popup that the WinForms applications display by default, and gives the user the option to continue or exit the app.

Comment: This solution is really good in order to achieve part of my goal. Moreover, I also noticed that it's more efficient than my implemenatation when I stop all threads with global variables.
However, I didn't find a way to handle single a thread with this kind of structure. I tried with somewhere like a list of booleans (or dictionary), but doesn't work. Is this a limit of your implementation?

Comment: **Edit:**
I found a mecanichal solution in order to remove a specific thread: stop all threads with global variables, remove thread id in dictionary and next run all threads again. In order to work, I use global variables to check while cycle.
What do you think? Is there a better way?

Comment: ​@GabrieleTroviso *"However, I didn't find a way to handle single a thread with this kind of structure."* -- Could you describe in more details what you mean by this? Does it have to do with exceptions? What is the desirable behavior, and what behavior do you observe instead?

Comment: I didn't talk about exceptions, but about threads in general. I would like stop or run single thread when I want as well as stop or run all threads. This is the reason I initially chose  a dictionary

Comment: @GabrieleTroviso if you want to process the objects on a single thread, just set the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to `1`. This way the objects will be processed the one after the other, sequentially. Or maybe you mean that you want to pause the processing at any moment, and resume it with a different `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` value?

Comment: @TheodoreZoulias I mean that I want to pause single thread at any moment. For example, if I throw 10 thread with `Parallel.ForEach(...)`, I will stop the third at any moment and, after few time, also restart it

Comment: @GabrieleTroviso check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705006/is-it-possible-to-change-paralleloptions-maxdegreeofparallelism-during-execution/71487926#71487926) that I have posted in another question about dynamic degree of parallelism. The property `DynamicParallelOptions.DegreeOfParallelism` has a setter that restricts it to be positive, but you could change the `if (value < 1)` to `if (value < 0)` to allow the value zero, and effectively suspend the parallel execution. I think it should work for your case.